# Radio Button List Auto Select first in MVC db populated list

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, radio-button

I have a table that gets a dynamic source list for each row, with a radio button for each row.  It's populated at runtime by MVC.  How do I automatically select the first one?

```
<table class="thisTable">
     <tr id="thisRow<%: a.Id %>">
        <% foreach (var t in myType) { %>

            <td id="myTypeCheck<%: a.Id %>">
<input type="radio" name="myType" checked id="<%: t.Id %>" onselect="myTypeChange('<%: t.Id %>')" /></td>

<td><%: t.Val %></td>

<% } %>

</table>
```

That's a basic representation of the table, how would I select the first one of the generated radio buttons?  I've tried checked in the input tag, no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a foreach loop, use a for loop.

Then if you are rendering the item at index zero, make the radio button's checked attribute checked as follows:

```
<table class="thisTable">

    <% for (int i = 0; i < myType.Count; i++) { %>
    <tr id="thisRow<%: a.Id %>">
        <td id="myTypeCheck<%: a.Id %>">

            <% if(i == 0) { %>
                <input type="radio" name="myType" 
                    checked="checked" id="<%: t.Id %>" 
                    onselect="myTypeChange('<%: t.Id %>')" />
            <% } else { %>
                <input type="radio" name="myType" 
                    id="<%: t.Id %>" 
                    onselect="myTypeChange('<%: t.Id %>')" />
            <% } %>
        </td>
        <td><%: t.Val %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Swaff!  While this works, I ended up finding this and ran it in a jQuery document.ready: `$('input[name=myType]:eq(0)').attr('checked', 'checked');`